# How to test if gems are compatible when upgrading ruby from 2.0.0-p247 to 2.4.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'd like to know if there is a method/gem/script that allows automating checking the compatibility of gems when upgrading ruby from v2.0.0-p247 to v2.4.6. I have run the **bundle install** which made me update a few of them and also, I ran my tests with **rake** and all are OK, but I'm not so sure if I can get further issues down the road.

Comment: How do you know that your *current* code is 100% perfect, and will not "run into issues down the road"?

Comment: The answer to both questions is the same: You don't know. But there are several things you can do to improve the application reliability, such as: You can peer-review the code; you can write automated tests; you can QA the application; you can use tooling to monitor errors in production; you can obtain feedback from end-users of the application, if they see some unexpected behaviour.

Comment: ...And if some issue is discovered that wasn't covered by any automated tests, you could *add a regression test* along with the fix.

Comment: Closing as duplicate doesn't help much when there's no completely helpful answer in the linked question.